# import variables into bash script from a config file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I would like to import variables like username, password, host name from a config.cfg file so that I can use them inside the bash script file script.sh

```
user = ""
password = ""
host = ""
```

how can I do that, so that in the script.sh file I can use the credentials that are set in the config.cfg file to excute the following in the script:

```
mysqldump --user="$user" --password="$password" --host="$host" $db $tabl > "./backups/$db/$db-$tabl-$time"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the spaces around the `=` signs in your config file, source it from your script, and use the so defined shell variables:

```
source config.cfg
echo "$user"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to *source* it. In `bash` you can do that using `source` or `.`, they are equivalents. For example:

```
source config.cfg
```

or

```
. config.cfg
```

**EDIT**:

As correctly noted in the other answer you need to remove spaces around `=` for your `config.cfg` to work in `bash`.

Comment: just reiterating. the command need to be `bash <scriptname.sh>`, not `sh <scriptname.sh>` .. thank you for pointing this out!